# Uniformization theorem imply that all the metric on 2-dimensional sphere are confromally equivalent?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, geometric-topology

In  [**Some inequalities in certain nonorientable Riemannian manifolds**](https://doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1952.2.55),
seemly, the author state that :   Assuming $S^2$ is 2-dimensional sphere.  $(S^2,g), (S^2,\tilde g)$ are two Riemannian manifold, where $g, \tilde g$ are two Riemannian metric. Then, there is $\lambda: S^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ such that
$$
g(p)=\lambda(p) \tilde g(p)  ~~~~~~~~ \forall p\in S^2 \tag{1}
$$
(The red line of first picture below.)

I find some reference, for example, in Wiki (the second picture below), seemly, it is right. But I am not sure, since my English is poor, and I am unfamiliar with Riemann sphere.  So, I want to know: whether $(1)$ is right for all metric on 2-dimensional sphere?

**PS(2023-10-11):** According to comments, I have the following understanding.

1st, There is a projective plane $(P^2, g_{P^2})$.

2nd, By the projection process $\pi:S^2\rightarrow P^2$, we get a metric on $S^2$. Denote it as $(S^2, g_{S^2})$.

3rd, By  Uniformization theorem, there is diffeomorphism $\phi:S^2\rightarrow U^2$ and function $\lambda: U^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ such that
$$
(\phi^{-1})^*g_{S^2}(x)=\lambda(x)g_E(x)  
~~~~~~\forall x\in U^2
$$
where  $U^2$ is unit 2-sphere and    $g_E$ is the induced metric of $U^2$ from Euclidean space.

4th, However, the proof also need $\forall x\in U^2,  \pi\circ \phi^{-1}(x)=\pi\circ\phi^{-1}(-x)$. This is an additional requirement. Although I feel such $\phi$ is existing, but I don't know how to show it.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Not quite, since it is easy to write a counterexample. There exists a diffeomorphism $\phi: S\rightarrow S$ and function $\lambda$ such that $$ g=\lambda \phi^*\tilde{g}. $$

Comment: I think there may be language issues going on with translating Riemannian Manifolds vs Riemann surfaces.

Comment: You should add a detailed quote from the paper. It is likely that you are misreading what it says.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  I have add the paper and the picture of it. Seemly, I neglect the word "arrange".  The "arrange" in the first picture should be the diffeomorphism, is it?

Comment: @Deane  I have add the picture of this paper. I think the word "arrange" should be your diffeomorphism. But he need the arrange such that "two diametrically opposite points of $U^2$ correspond to the same point of $M_{~p^2}^2$".  So, the existence of such diffeomorphism is not obvious for me.

Comment: @Deane  And, according your statement,  Pu's proof seemly be problematic.

Comment: The part where it says "we can map" is where the diffeomorphism $\phi$ is hidden.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, I write my understanding above.  Is it right ?